# Set user- or group-specific MOTD in SSH

Tags: ssh, motd

I would like to disable or change the MOTD shown on SSH login on a per-group/per-user basis. [This question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/704590/can-i-disable-ssh-last-login-and-motd-on-a-per-user-basis) has an answer stating that I can use `Match` blocks in `sshd_config`. However, `man sshd_config` states:

```
Match
         ...
         Only a subset of keywords may be used on the lines following a
         Match keyword.  Available keywords are AcceptEnv,
         AllowAgentForwarding, AllowGroups, AllowTcpForwarding,
         AllowUsers, AuthenticationMethods, AuthorizedKeysCommand,
         AuthorizedKeysCommandUser, AuthorizedKeysFile,
         AuthorizedPrincipalsFile, Banner, ChrootDirectory, DenyGroups,
         DenyUsers, ForceCommand, GatewayPorts, GSSAPIAuthentication,
         HostbasedAuthentication, HostbasedUsesNameFromPacketOnly,
         KbdInteractiveAuthentication, KerberosAuthentication,
         MaxAuthTries, MaxSessions, PasswordAuthentication,
         PermitEmptyPasswords, PermitOpen, PermitRootLogin, PermitTTY,
         PermitTunnel, PubkeyAuthentication, RekeyLimit,
         RhostsRSAAuthentication, RSAAuthentication, X11DisplayOffset,
         X11Forwarding and X11UseLocalHost.
```

And I can't see anything related to MOTD in that list. And indeed, trying to use that suggestion causes `sshd` to fail to start because of incorrect configuration.

So, can I do this? If so, how? From the SSH configuration or by altering whatever generates/prints the MOTD?

---

Altering files in `/etc/update-motd.d` isn't useful, since, according to [`man update-motd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/update-motd):

```
   Executable  scripts in /etc/update-motd.d/* are executed by pam_motd(8)
   as the root user at each login, and this information is concatenated in
   /var/run/motd.
```

(I tested this out with a script that did `echo $USER`. I got a `root` in my MOTD.)

That leaves PAM configuration. I imagine it might be possible to disable `pam_motd` on a per-group/user basis, but I am not sure how to do it. The last option would be to disable `pam_motd` altogether, and use `pam_exec`, but I really hope it doesn't come to that.

Comment: I agree with your analisys, reading manual it seems that it in not possible use `Match` directive with `PrintMotd`. Another approach could be define your own script with custom user/group output in `/etc/update-motd.d`, did you consider this?

Comment: @Letizia I did. I was hoping for something involving SSH itself or via PAM, but if SSH configuration isn't an option and PAM configuration gets too complex, I'll probably add a `11-custom` script and disable some of the others.

Comment: About disable motd output, did you see `HUSHLOGIN_FILE` directive in `/etc/login.defs`?

Comment: Did you try `session optional pam_exec.so seteuid /path/to/script` in this context I guess PAM_USER variable value should be right.

Comment: @Letizia I knew of per-user .hushlogin files, but not of the central one. Since apparently only one of the two can be used, and because my use case is with LDAP of 1000+ users and I'd like some freedom for the user to disable or enable motd, a central file is doubly ineffective.

Comment: @Letizia No, as I said in the question `pam_exec` with custom scripts is the last option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an implementation on per user/group motd inspired by [motd or login banner per user](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/motd-or-login-banner-per-user-699925/)

First comment out:

```
session    optional   pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
session    optional   pam_motd.so
```

in `/etc/pam.d/login` and set `PrintMotd no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Then you could define your per user/group message script and put it in folder, for example:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/mymotd/groups
sudo mkdir -p /etc/mymotd/users
```

In these folders you can create executable scripts for each groups or users that prints on standard output the message of the day.

You could create `/etc/profile.d/perUserGroupMotd.sh` with the follow lines:

```
gidName=`id -gn`
if [ -e /etc/mymotd/groups/$gidName ]; then
   /etc/mymotd/groups/$gidName
else 
   if [ -e /etc/mymotd/users/$USER ]; then
      /etc/mymotd/users/$USER
   fi
fi
```

or you can use file to enable/disable message and than run `/path/to/script -g $gidName` or `/path/to/script -u $USER`, obviously there are many different possible implementations.

About `pam_motd`, at the end I found these two bug:

- [pam_motd runs commands as root with unsanitised environment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/610125): this is a security hole and `update-motd` patch is: unset environment and manually set `PATH` variable.
- [Multiple issues with pam_motd update-motd code](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/684244): one of this multiple issues is about a missing lock on file generated by `update-motd`. In multi-user system, multiple concurrent access can result in corrupted motd.

For these reasons I guess is not possible to use `pam_motd` for your objective.

`HUSHLOGIN_FILE` directive in `/etc/login.defs` should *inhibits all the usual chatter during the login sequence*, so any output is suppressed even last login date.

I guess that motd is designed to reach all user in the system and because of this `ssh` and `pam_motd` simple enable or disable it for all user.

Comment: Suggestions: Instead of editing `/etc/profile`, recommend adding scripts to `/etc/profile.d`. Cleaner. And when you say "Another approach is write /etc/update-motd.d script ...", you mean without disabling `pam_motd`?

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `/etc/profile.d`, you're always accurate :) and sorry for pam_motd, I forgot to delete those paragraphs before posting answer :( Now I added information found that would give us an explanation of why is not possible to accomplish your target with `pam_motd`